# How to build Android system with option -g -O0

Tags: android, build, lldb, codelldb

I want the whole android system component contain debug symbols and debug info.
So I need build c and c++ files with option -g and -O0.
Then how to do it? How to change Android.bp file to get this?
I want to build the whole system with such options and use VS code to debug it via lldb.
My source code is located in remote linux server and my workstation is a windows computer.